vite + react + pnpm: build fails with "default" is not exported by
I am working on a pnpm workspace monorepo with the following layout:
 /packages/backend
 /packages/frontend
 /packages/shared

Vite builds fine when developing locally. The react app renders without issue.
However, when I run vite build it fails when it tries to bundle react aria with the following error:
✓ 2581 modules transformed.
x Build failed in 8.62s
error during build:
RollupError: ../../node_modules/.pnpm/@react-aria+ssr@3.9.2_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@react-aria/ssr/dist/import.mjs (1:7): "default" is not exported by "../../node_modules/.pnpm/react@18.2.0/node_modules/react/index.js", imported by "../../node_modules/.pnpm/@react-aria+ssr@3.9.2_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@react-aria/ssr/dist/import.mjs".
file: /Users/wmonecke/Documents/Code/[project]/node_modules/.pnpm/@react-aria+ssr@3.9.2_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@react-aria/ssr/dist/import.mjs:1:7
1: import $73SJx$react, {useContext as $73SJx$useContext, useState as $73SJx$useState, useMemo as $73SJx$useMemo, useLay...
This error is very similar to this issue from vite
This is my vite.config.ts
/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */

import { resolve } from 'path';

import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  return {
    envDir: `../../`,
    plugins: [
      react(),
      svgr(),
      eslint({
        failOnError: false,
        include: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
      }),
    ],
    optimizeDeps: {
      include: ['@fabled/shared', '@react-aria'],
    },
    build: {
      commonjsOptions: {
        include: ['@fabled/shared'],
      },
    },

    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '~': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      },
    },
  };
});

and my tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "allowJs": false,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "include": ["./src", "./src/**/*.d.ts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

tsconfig.node.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}

and my package.json
{
  "name": "@fabled/frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The frontend for the Fabled project",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "check-types": "tsc --pretty --noEmit",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "dev": "vite",
    "format": "npx prettier --write src/**/*.{ts,tsx} --config .prettierrc.cjs",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test:ci": "exit 0"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "bash -c \"pnpm format\"",
      "eslint --ext ts,tsx,js,jsx --fix",
      "bash -c \"pnpm check-types\"",
      "bash -c \"pnpm test:ci\""
    ],
    "*.{json,md,css,scss}": [
      "bash -c \"pnpm format\""
    ]
  },
  "dependenciesMeta": {
    "@fabled/shared": {
      "injected": true
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fabled/shared": "workspace:*",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.2",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.16.4",
    "@nextui-org/checkbox": "^2.0.25",
    "@nextui-org/popover": "^2.1.14",
    "@nextui-org/system": "^2.0.15",
    "@nextui-org/theme": "^2.1.17",
    "@nextui-org/tooltip": "^2.0.30",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^2.0.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.0",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.4.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.12",
    "i18next": "^23.7.11",
    "intl-pluralrules": "^2.0.1",
    "lucide-react": "^0.300.0",
    "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-animate-height": "^3.2.3",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.2",
    "react-i18next": "^13.5.0",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.20.1",
    "react-use-measure": "^2.1.1",
    "recharts": "^2.12.1",
    "reduxjs-toolkit-persist": "^7.2.1",
    "rooks": "^7.14.1",
    "sonner": "^1.2.4",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@types/loadable__component": "^5.13.9",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.41",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "@types/react-loadable": "^5.5.11",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.32",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.54.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.54.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "core-js": "^3.29.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "eslint-plugin-check-file": "^2.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-function-name": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^13.1.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "0.5.9",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.10.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.6",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^5.2.10",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.8.1",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^2.4.0"
  }
}

How can I handle .mjs files or bundle them properly?
I am sure there is a way because it works fine when in development mode.
Thank you!
